# How to convert Attachment Object to ByteArray in JAVA

Tags: java, serialization, cxf, deserialization, multipart

I am writing a web service in JAVA using Apache CXF.

So, I have a method whose prototype is following:

```
public Response upload(@Multipart("id") int Id, 
            @Multipart("file") Attachment attachment) {
```

Now, I want to convert this attachment to byte[] . How can I do it?

Comment: Do you wan to read the content of the attachemt to a byte array, or you want to serialize it ? Please clarify your question because it;s unclear what you are asking

Comment: Finally , I have to store it as a BLOB in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can read the content of the attachment and store it inside a byte array. Alternatively you can write directly to an `OutputStream` and skip the conversion to `byte[]`.

```
        DataHandler dataHandler = attachment.getDataHandler();
        final byte[] data;
        try (InputStream inputStream = dataHandler.getInputStream()) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            for (int read = inputStream.read(buffer); read > 0; read = inputStream.read(buffer)) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            data = outputStream.toByteArray();
        }

        //todo write data to BLOB
```

If you want to be more memory efficient or if the attachment does not fit into memory, you can write directly to the blob's output stream. Just replace the `ByteArrayOutputStream` with `OutputStream outputStream = blob.setBinaryStream(1);`